# if $\lim\int f^n \,d\mu$ exists as a finite number, show that $|f|\leq 1$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space and assume $f^{n}$ is integrable for all $n=0$, $1$, $2,\ \ldots$ and if $\lim\int f^n\, d\mu$ exists as a finite number, show that $|f|\leq 1$ almost everywhere.

We need to show that $\{x:f(x)<-1\}\cup \{x:1<f(x)\}$ is set of measure zero. Suppose not. Assume $A:=\{x:1<f(x)\}$ has nonzero measure. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $x \in A$, $f^n(x)>\epsilon/ \mu(A)$. So   $\int_A f^n>\int_A \epsilon /\mu(A)=\epsilon$. So $\lim\int f^n=\infty$, contradiction. Can any one check my answer? And how about the other case $B:=\{x:f(x)<-1\}$ has nonzero measure. I couldn't see this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the correct way. But be careful, you can't say that for any $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in A$ it is $f^n(x)>\epsilon/ \mu(A).$ If you assume that the measure of the set $\{x:f(x)>1\}$ is not zero then for some $\epsilon>0$ the measure of $\{x:f(x)\ge 1+\epsilon\}$ is not zero. Now, on this set $f^n(x)\ge (1+\epsilon)^n \to \infty.$

In the set $\{x:f(x)<-1\}$ you can use the same argument, noting only the change of sign depending on $n$ odd or even.

Answer (score 1):

Although you are fairly close, your proof is not correct and it shows in your inability to fit the set $\{f<-1\}$ in the framework.  In your proof you are not making substantial use of the fact that $|f|>1$.  If it worked, replace $|f|>1$ by $|f|>1/2$ and your argument goes through with no changes, but obviously the conclusion $\lim\int f^n = \infty$ cannot be guaranteed.

Here is a way to mend your proof.  You do not need to separate the two sets, just use $A=\{x:|f|>1\}$ and assume for contradiction that $m(A)>0$.  Note that $A$ is the countable union of sets $A_k=\{x:|f|>1+\frac{1}{k}\}$ where $k$ runs through all positive integers: $A=\cup_k A_k$.  Check this.

Therefore at least one of the $A_k$ has positive measure, other wise the countable union would have measure zero.  So pick $k$ with $m(A_k)=m>0.$

Now apply your procedure to that integral:
$$\int|f|^n\geq \int_{A_k} |f|^n \geq \int_{A_k} (1+\frac{1}{k})^n = m(1+\frac{1}{k})^n.$$

Now since $m>0$ and $k$ is a positive integer $1+\frac{1}{k}>1$ so we have a number greater than one raised to the $n$'th power.  Thus as $n\to \infty$ the last quantity tends to infinity, showing what you wanted.